# Java and MySQL - How to design classes when foriegn keys are involved

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pojo

## MySQL Schema

### building

id (PK), address

### room

id (PK), buildingid (FK referencing building table)

### sensor

id (PK), roomid (FK referencing room table), activated

## Java Classes

```
public class Building {
    private int id;
    private String address;
    private List<Room> rooms;
}

public class Room {
    private int id;
    private List<Sensor> sensors;
}

public class Sensor {
    private int id;
    private boolean activated;
}
```

I have a method with the following signature

```
public Building getBuilding(int id) {
    // get address from building table
    // get rooms from room table
    // for each room
        // get sensors from sensor table
    // return building object
}
```

I am not sure if reading the entire data every time is a good idea. Is there an inherent design issue here? Any pointers to design patterns or best practices here would be useful.

P.S. I haven't worked with any frameworks like Hibernate earlier

Comment: This depends on your requirements. There's no clear-cut answer.

Comment: completely opinion based here: don't use foreign key at all.

Comment: In the situation you described,
the foreign keys are defining an association hierarchy.
Your current class design is fine.  Just allow for empty lists in Building and Room and only load what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit broad, but I'll give it a try

> I am not sure if reading the entire data every time is a good idea

Ideally, you should load the exact amount of data you need. If you need everything, then there's no going around it.

If you have multiple use cases, where you need specific data about the building (or whatever else), you can create multiple classes to represent them and load them using different queries, for example:

```
class BuildingWithAddress {
  int id
  String address;
}

class BuildingWithSensors {
  int id
  List<Sensor> sensors;
}

// etc.
```

> Is there an inherent design issue here?

No. The classes you designed look fine, and depending on your use cases, might be enough.

> Any pointers to design patterns or best practices here would be useful.

- don't overthink it and start with a simple solution
- load just the data you need, either through multiple classes or [lazy loading](https://dzone.com/articles/lazyeager-loading-using)
- avoid performing multiple queries to retrieve a single logical entity
- if necessary, [denormalize your database](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/denormalization-when-why-and-how)